# How to implement GeoDjango PointField Widget in Wagtail?

Tags: python, wagtail, geodjango

I am trying to get the GeoDjango PointField widget to work in Wagtail, i.e. is there a way to use the functionalitiy provided by `OSMGeoAdmin` in the Wagtail admin?

In my vanilla django `admin.py` I simply have:

```
# admin.py
from django.contrib.gis.admin import OSMGeoAdmin
from .models import Location

@admin.register(Location)
class LocationAdmin(OSMGeoAdmin):
    list_display = ('name', 'location')
```

Which works as intended, i.e. displaying the OpenStreet widget. But in my `wagtail_hooks.py` simply inheriting from `OSMGeoAdmin` doesn’t work and `ModelAdmin` only gives me an OpenLayers widget with a NASA worldview layer.

```
# wagtail_hooks.py
from wagtail.contrib.modeladmin.options import ModelAdmin, modeladmin_register
from wagtail.admin.edit_handlers import FieldPanel
from .models import Location

class LocationAdmin(ModelAdmin):
    model = Location
    menu_label = "Location"
    menu_icon = "pick"
    panels = [
        FieldPanel("name"),
        FieldPanel("location"),
    ]

modeladmin_register(LocationAdmin)
```

Is there a Wagtail panel I am missing or any other way to get the OpenStreet widget into my Wagtail admin view?

Comment: Have you seen https://github.com/Frojd/wagtail-geo-widget? That should have a good indication on how to approach this

Comment: Yeah, I peaked into it. I even tried to adapt it, but it is a bit of a challenge for my skills. But, well, maybe that's the way to go. Thanks again for pointing it out.